# Getting Error while running python3 main.py file

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I am getting this error,

```
/tmp/Python-3.7.5$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 65, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 119, in <module>
    from pandas.core import algorithms, common as com, generic, nanops, ops
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 112, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats import format as fmt
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 77, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import stringify_path
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 3, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

what is the solution?

Comment: This is *some* error log that you're having. Could you describe your setup, environment and other details so that we have a better understanding of your problem ?
Also, have you googled or SO-ed this problem ?

Comment: When I tried to run directly Python main.py, It shows me an error for pandas, then I installed pandas, after installation of pandas get this error. Actually I am new to this and installing on linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install your Python? If you've manually built it or used the make command, you might be missing the bz2 library headers.

Try the following...

Centos/Fedora/RHEL:

```
sudo yum install bzip2-devel
```

Debian and Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

You'll then either need to rebuild your Python installation or to copy the header in your Python folder, with:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/
```

Comment: Glad I could help!